# Hibernate: Accessing created entity from different transaction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am having quite complex methods which create different entities during its execution and use them. For instance, I create some images and then I add them to an article:

```
@Transactional
public void createArticle() {
  List<Image> images = ...
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      // creating some new images, method annotated @Transactional
      images.add(repository.createImage(...));
  }

  Article article = getArticle();
  article.addImages(images);
  em.merge(article);
}
```

This correctly works – images have their IDs and then they are added to the article. The problem is that during this execution the database is locked and nothing can be modified. This is very unconvinient because images might be processed by some graphic processor and it might take some time.

So we might try to remove the `@Transactional` from the main method. This could be good.
What happens is that images are correctly created and have their ID. But once I try to add them to `article` and call merge, I get `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` for Image with ID XXXX. The entity manager can't see that the image was created and have its ID. So the database is not locked, but we can't do anything either.

So what can I do? I don't want to have the database locked during the whole execution and I want to be able to access the created entities!

I am using current version of Spring and Hibernate, everything defined by Annotations. I don't use session factory, I am accessing everything via `javax.persistence.EntityManager`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider leveraging the Hibernate cascading functionality for persisting object trees in one go with minimal database locking:

```
@Entity
public class Article {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<Images> images;
}

@Transactional
public void createArticle() {
    //images created as Java objects in memory, no DAOs called yet
    List<Image> images = ...  
    Article article = getArticle();
    article.addImages(images);
    // cascading will save the article AND the images
    em.merge(article);
}
```

Like this the article AND it's images will get persisted at the end of the transaction in a single transaction with a minimal lifetime. Up until then no locking occurred on the database.

Alternativelly split the `createArticle` in two `@Transactional` business methods, one `createImages` and the other `addImagesToArticle` and call them one after the other in a third method in another bean:

```
@Service
public class OtherBean {
    @Autowired
    private YourService yourService;    

    // note that no transactional annotation is used, this is intentional
    public otherMethod() {
        yourService.createImages(); // first transaction - images are committed

        yourService.addImagesToArticle(); // second transaction - images are added to article
    }
}
```

Comment: Ad 1: This could be good solution, but I forgot to mention the fact, that when creating images, I need to know their ID, so that they can be saved to disk. I suppose unless I start saving them by their hashes, the DB call will be inevitable. However I still think it would work if all the calls to DB were separate.

Comment: Ad 2: I have actually tried this, but this leads to `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` as if the two transactions were unaware of each other.

Comment: try generating the image Id without blocking, with @SequenceGenerator. This will create the ID by calling a database sequence, but it won't trigger the insert of the entity itself immediatellyhttp://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/UseSequenceGenerator.htm. Like that you have the ID and can use it before commiting the insert of the image itself

Comment: and how do you get the EntityNotFoundException? if you could post the stacktrace, but it means refresh, lock or getReference was called to an entity with an ID that no longer/not yet exists in the DB. can you post the code for the attempt that gives this error, it seems the first transaction is not committed because the calling method is itself transactional and unintencional propagation occurs

Comment: I don't know how, but now it seems to be working. I will accept your answer then. (you may award your bounty in 2 hours)

Comment: hi @Vojtěch, I think you need to assign the bounty yourself, see here on How do I award a bounty section http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work , thanks

Comment: Yes, I know, (you may award you bounty in 2 hours) meant that I couldn't assign it too soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the transaction isolation on your datasource to READ_UNCOMMITTED, though that can lead to inconsistencies so it is generally not a recommended thing to do.

Comment: I tried to use this, but the exception said it is not allowed within Hibernate. Anyway – I would not like to READ_UNCOMMITTED – I would prefer to commit the changes and to work with them.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that your transaction isolation level is SERIALIZABLE. That's why the DB locks affected tables for the whole duration of a transaction.
If that's the case change the level to READ_COMMITTED. Hibernate (or any JPA provider) works nicely with this one. 
It won't lock anything unless you explicitly call `entityManager.lock(someEntity, LockModeType.SomeLockType))`
Also when you choose transaction boundaries firstly think in terms of atomicity. If createArticle() is an atomic unit of work it just has to be made transactional, breaking it into smaller transactions for the sake of 'optimization' is wrong.